# Need help creating SQLite trigger for keeping running totals

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

This is my first attempt at creating a trigger and I'm confused. Here's the basic database schema with the pertinent columns:

```
DATABASE_NAME

TABLE_100               
| C100_ROWID | C101_NAME | ... | C105_COUNT |

TABLE_200               
| C200_ROWID | C201_NAME | ... | C207_FOREIGNKEY (C101_NAME) |
```

TABLE_100 is created first, then TABLE_200's rows are populated based on user input, so TABLE_200 is empty when the application is first launched.

What I'm trying to do is create a trigger when there is an INSERT on TABLE_200, to ADD +1 to the C105_COUNT of the specific C101_NAME row that was used as the C207_FOREIGNKEY.

The purpose is to keep a running total of all the times C101_ROWID/C100_NAME is used in TABLE_200.

Here's what I got so far and it's obviously completely wrong so any help would be appreciated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER runningcount AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_200
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE_100
    SET C105_COUNT = C105_COUNT + 1
    WHERE (??? newly inserted row on TABLE_200 ???) C207_FOREIGNKEY = C101_NAME
END
```

Edit:

I figured it out after about 2 hours of frustration. In case anyone needs this in the future:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_200
    BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE_100
        SET C105_COUNT = C105_COUNT + 1
        WHERE C101_NAME = new.C207_FOREIGNKEY
    END
```

Comment: Please put your answer not into the question but in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after about 2 hours of frustration. In case anyone needs this in the future:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_200
    BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE_100
        SET C105_COUNT = C105_COUNT + 1
        WHERE C101_NAME = new.C207_FOREIGNKEY
    END
```